# Angular shared Module component import error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a shared module in Angular which I then import in all other modules. The shared modules imports the other modules and some common components that are used across the project.

My issue is that the while the modules like the material module is successfully being exported to the other modules the components being created are giving compilation error.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    // SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { ToolbarComponent } from './toolbar/toolbar.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ToolbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  exports: [
    NgbModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ToolbarComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**home-page.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

While I am able to import the material modules components, I am unable to import the ToolbarComponent

The Error I received on using the selector  for the ToolbarComponent

```
Error: src/app/home-page/home-page.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'app-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Comment: You copy paste twice the `HomePageModule`, I think you wanted to post your `AppModule`

Comment: Sometimes HotReload doesn't work with Module Changes. The solution could be to re-serve your project to trigger a new full build.

Comment: you need to import the SharedModule in the HomePageModule and add the ToolbarComponent to the declarations array.

Comment: Thank you so much @Andres2142 for pointing out the mistake. I have also added the ToolbarComponent in the declaration and export of the shared.module.ts this was done similar to the [medium article](https://mobinaya.medium.com/shared-module-in-angular-bc56f8264b2e)